# Can we give higher priority certain features in machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, feature-engineering, importance

I am preparing a model for predicting the customer propensity to buy from our company. We are using the transaction data for modelling. On discussion with our sales team, we realized that some features are of higher importance and they should have more say in the prediction. They insist on giving weight to these features in the model.
Is it possible to give more prominence to certain features in the model (in any model)? Is it advisable to do so?
What are the pros and cons of this approach? How should I convince the team for or against it?

Comment: Your model will already attempt to find the best prediction (as evaluated by your loss function). There are various importance measures for predictors. I would recommend fitting your model and then looking at feature importance. If the importance is as expected, good. If not, the question really is whether the sales team's beliefs are consonant with reality. In any case, you should definitely test the opinions of the sales team against your data. ...

Comment: Why do they want this? What if you find out that another variable has more predictive power than their selected ones, will they be happy with a worse result?

Comment: ... For instance, does using the single "most important" predictor in a very simple model already outperform a baseline model (e.g., one that assigns the same probabilty to each customer)? Does such a simple one-predictor model outperform an automatically built model with all predictors? And so forth.